# how to set Text in actionBar Sherlock programmatically

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Below is my application header and I want to set current date-time in "DD/MM" place. How can I do this programmatically ? I am using actionBarSherlock

[image]

This is how I have set the background:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs_bg</item>
        <item name="background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Could you provide a code sample of how you build the header?

Comment: The header is an image, there is not textview yet.I have added code. See the question's edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to use any option menu or any other actionBarSherlock functionality, then there is no need to this library. You can use any theme with *`NoTitleBar`* and create a custom `RelativeLayout` t create the header.

**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
 <!--Anything -->
</style>
```

**Your layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#6ccff6">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/abs_bg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="July 25"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Put any other layout/view here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding, but you could just add a `MenuItem` which does nothing, set to be that text (although that's probably a bad way to do it).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    String currentTime;
    // Calculate your string
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, currentTime);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I think that'd be a way to do it, although I'm not sure how good it would look.

**Edit:** You could also get rid of the highlighted blue section of the ActionBar upon the MenuItem being pressed by setting a custom background. Underneath is a quick way to do that (assuming you only have that MenuItem):

```
<style name="BlankMenu" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/CustomItem</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomItem" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
    <item name="background">@drawable/transparent</item>
</style>
```

When `@drawable/transparent` being a 1x1 transparent PNG. Just set your theme to be `BlankMenu` in your Manifest.

You could also probably rework the theme to give the MenuItem a blue background by default and remove the blue section from your ActionBar theme if your aim was to only have the date surrounded by a blue background. It'd probably make it more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom layout for the header in XML, inflate/findViewById for that and update the date, then call [setCustomView(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28android.view.View%29) on your ActionBar object.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
LinearLayout actionBarView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.action_bar_view, null);
((TextView) actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate)).setText(CURRENT_DATE);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);            
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

EDIT: Also, if you wanted to set Custom View from a resource ID, you could call setCustomView(int resID) and then use getCustomView to make actual changes to the view, which would be more useful if you had data that needed to change multiple times or after the actionBar was created.